# Can someone identify this odd looking spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I found this spider crawling on my tile floor. We live in rural central Virginia.  I’ve found spider species with similar looks but nothing exactly like this. Its size was less than 1 inch. Can anyone identify it?[image]

Comment: Some sort of jumping spider (Family: Salticidae)

Comment: Could be Thiodina sylvana... But I'm not sure. Thiodina occurs in Virginia. Take a look at this picture: https://www.flickr.com/photos/52450054@N04/6304831786 but be careful, it shows a male. Females tend to be more brownish

Answer (score 2):

I agree with JulPal's comment from August.  It looks very much like a male *Thiodina* (now renamed *Colonus*) *sylvanus*.  As with many Salticids, the females look rather different, and it turns out that there is apparently a similar species of *Colonus* in the area, which can be distinguished in the field by the fact that the white mark on the carapace is not a block so much as a thick longitudinal line.
I attach an image from Tree of Life, with the link below:

[image]

http://www.tolweb.org/Thiodina_sylvana/5911

Answer (score -4):

It is Tarantula which comprise a group of large and often hairy arachnids belonging to the Theraphosidae family of spiders

Comment: It would be good to explain how you know it is a tarantula. Maybe based on on the position of the chelicerae? I am surprised that there are tarantula as far North as Virginia.

Comment: It doesn’t look at all like a Tarantula to me. It’s size was less than 1 inch.

Comment: @Penni You should be mentioning that in the question. From this zoom, I would have guessed that it was much bigger.

Comment: Yes, I should have.. my bad. This is my first post, ever, so I’m a newbie. Thanks for your help, @TheLastWord. 

Comment: It is not a Mygalomorph - the eyes are in the front of the head,  with two large ones right on the forward 'face', like a Jumping Spider, rather than clustered in a turret atop the round, flat carapace; the abdomen is long and teardrop-shaped, like a Jumping Spider, rather than large and bulky, with two obvious 'exhaust-pipe' spinnerets at the back; and the legs are short and stocky, like a Jumping Spider, rather than long and thick and very hairy.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that it's a jumping spider. Tarantulas look nothing even remotely close to that.